Neovim key command r is to be customized
As in neovim key command:
r

is to get into insert mode await a key being hit then automatically go back to normal
Then does neovim have possible way to append it a key sequence, e.g. l that is can automatically go to right
It'd be preferred being a Lua keybinding
Please help

In vim, r is use to go in replace mode to replace a single character. For replacing multiple characters consecutively while staying in replace mode use R. Also see :h Replace
